# Update DOM of popup.html after clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension. I want to update a `h3` element in `popup.html` with some text after click a submit button with id `submit`.

```html
<!-- popup.html -->
<div class="row">
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
</div>
```

```js
// popup.js
function saveClass() {
    var status = document.getElementById('status')
    status.innerText = 'success';
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", saveClass);
```

The function populates the element with the text, and I see the text, but it disappears immediately, within some microseconds. Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: The button is submitting the form, which reloads the page.

Comment: @Terry Thanks! I have posted an answer below for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form refreshes the page by default upon submission, due to which the populated text vanishes. Just add an event listener to disable it, which keeps the DOM intact.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me its' working fine. You can refer the following code snippet

```
<html>

<body>
    <!-- popup.html -->
    <div class="row">
        <h3 id="status"></h3>
    </div>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    <!-- popup.js -->
    <script>
    
        function saveClass() {
            var status = document.getElementById('status')
            status.innerText = 'success';
        }
        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", saveClass);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is vanilla JavaScript. Chrome extensions function in a slightly different way, and do not allow to use some tag attributes for security purposes. Thanks for helping.